# WPF CommandParameter is null despite being bound

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, commandparameter

I'm stumped on this one.  Why would a command parameter be continuously empty despite being bound to a property that has a value.

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="CatalogInterface.ctlMainButtonPanel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CatalogInterface"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         x:Name="MainButtonPanel">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:MainButtonPanelViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    <!--#region Button Style-->
    <!--#region  FocusVisual-->
    <!--#endregion FocusVisual-->
    <!--#region Button-->
    <!--#endregion Button-->
    <!--#endregion Button Style-->
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">

<!--/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
<!--////////This is the button that won't pass the CommandParameter//////////////////-->
<!--/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
        <Button x:Name="cmdConvertToFBook" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedDocument}"
                Command="{Binding ConvertToFacebookCommand}" 
                Content="CONVERT TO FACEBOOK"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  
                Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
</UserControl>
```

View Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace CatalogInterface
{
    class MainButtonPanelViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Messanger _messanger = Messanger.Set_Messanger();
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////This is the property I'm binding my commandparameter to//////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////            
        private object _selectedDocument
        public object SelectedDocument
        {
            get { return _selectedDocument; }
            set { _selectedDocument = value; }
        }
        public ConvertToFacebookCommand ConvertToFacebookCommand { get; set; }

        public MainButtonPanelViewModel()
        {
            ConvertToFacebookCommand = new ConvertToFacebookCommand();
            _messanger.Register(OnSentMessage, "DirFilesListBox_SelectedDocumentChanged");
        }

        public void OnSentMessage(object source, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            _selectedDocument = e.MessageObject;
        }
    }
    public class ConvertToFacebookCommand : SingleFuncitonBaseCommand
    {
        public override void ButtonFunction(object parameter)
        {
            ConvertToFacebookFn.Convert(parameter);
        }

        public override void NotExacutable(object parameter)
        {
            ButtonNotExacutable.Report(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace CatalogInterface
{
    public abstract class SingleFuncitonBaseCommand : ICommand
    {
        private bool _canExecute { get; set; } = true;
        public SingleFuncitonBaseCommand()
        {

        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public virtual bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public virtual void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (_canExecute && parameter != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _canExecute = false;
                    ButtonFunction(parameter);
                }
                finally
                {
                    _canExecute = true;
                }
                return;
            }
            NotExacutable(parameter);
        }
        public abstract void ButtonFunction(object parameter);
        public abstract void NotExacutable(object parameter);
    }
}
```

My `SelectedDocument` property is being set by the `OnSentMessage` event that updates the property when the user clicks on a File in a list box.  I believe the object is a FileInfo object.  I can confirm the event is firing properly and the property is being set.

Also if i change my `SelectedDocument` property to a readonly property and set it to a `FileInfo` object it then does get passed to the parameter.

Is it possible for my `OnSentMessage` event and CommandParameter binding to be operating on two different objects?

How can I debug this further?

Thanks All.

Comment: Where is `OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDocument")` in the setter of your `SelectedDocument` ?

Comment: Where do you use `OnSentMessage` ?

Comment: "Is it possible for my OnSentMessage event and CommandParameter binding to be operating on two different objects"? Well possible, but we can't tell unless you show us all relevant parts of your code. How do you access or modify the UserControl's ViewModel resource?

Comment: You can use PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High to debug your CommandParameter binding.

Comment: Well, i solved based on all your responses.  @swiszcz PresentationTraceSources is an awesome feature, thanks for that helped a lot. @Clemens - OnSentMessage gets registered in my messaging class, it works for sure so I just didn't show it.  I register it using the `_messanger.Register(OnSentMessage, "DirFilesListBox_SelectedDocumentChanged");` line in the constructor of the ViewModel.  @AnjumSKhan - you were right I didn't put `OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDocument")` and I didn't catch it because there's another issue - the OnSentMessage listener sets the private property `_selectedDocument`.

Comment: If i put `OnPropertyChanged("SelectedDocument")` in the setter and change `OnSentMessage` to set `SelectedDocument` instead of `_selectedDocument` it works.  Can one of you write an answer so I can mark it right?